# transfer c_ptr (from c_loc) in c_long

Tags: pointers, casting, fortran

I would like to get the c_long value of a c_loc pointer:

```
type(c_ptr)  :: ref
type(c_long) :: val
ref=c_loc(my_struct%data)
val=transfer(ref, c_long)
```

Is it wrong? It seems to be the origin of my bug (which appears randomly).

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you want to get the *address* of `my_struct%data`? Why?

Comment: Yes I want the adress in c_long in order to get a memory displacement according to a reference memory location.

Comment: Mhm... I'm not sure Fortran is well suited for that... The compiler is at liberty to change the layout in memory of your derived type unless you define them as `sequence` (or `bind(c)` if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: No, you are right Alexander. But maybe he just examines the alignment produced by the compiler. But we certainly need more information about the problem. The eror message at least.

Comment: Also `c_long` is not the right kind for `c_ptr` same way as `long is not the right integer type for `void` pointers. You should use `c_intptr_t` in Fortran and `intptr_t` in C.

Comment: What about [`MPI_Get_address()`](http://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.5/man3/MPI_Get_address.3.php)? If you are just interested in the *difference* of addresses that might be sufficient... It requires MPI, of course.

Comment: OK thanks for your answers. The solution I've found is to do that in C (with t he C_F_pointer function) and to type it with intptr_t ! The solution is now stable.